# Input text has password indication icon

Tags: forms, input, text

In my form input I have a simple

input type="text" but the field is showing password icon why is this happening? [input text  field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d7Sq.png)

Comment: Maybe you could try to change it to `<input type="text" />` (note the / before closing the tag)? Not sure but might make it work.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: I believe input is a self closing tag, /> is not working. Correct me if I'm wrong.